# Fragments in a ViewPager – Tapping a button inside current frag effects the fragment after it NOT the current/visible frag

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragment-lifecycle

**Problem**: Upon clicking a button in a `fragment` inside of the `ViewPager` the click falls through to the `fragment` that is behind it and registers the `onClickListener()` in the behind `fragment` rather than the current fragment’s `onClickListener()`.

**Situation**: I have a `ViewPager` with 4 `fragments` in it. Each `fragment` contains a few rows of custom made buttons. Each `fragment` has it’s own unique `view/layout`, yet they are all designed similarly.

**Set Up**: I am using the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, because I have a short list of pretty static `fragments` AND because I need to communicate and update each `fragment` by using an `interface`, like how the developer docs suggest.

**My Idea**: Should I switch to the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? So the `adapter` will destroy the `fragments` when they are not visible? But in doing this, will I not be able to communicate with the `fragments` and update them accordingly?

I don’t know how to solve this problem and it has been driving me mad! Any help is appreciated.

Ask me if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the `fragment` behind/after/to-the-right of the current `fragment` in the `viewpager` was catching the button clicks was because of the use of the `PageTransformer` class that I used to add a fade out animation to the pages upon sliding. This `PageTransformer` animation messed everything up on android version 4.1.1 API 16 and version 4.2.2 API 17. SO be weary of using `PageTransformer`, especially if you want to support older android versions.